# No se encuentra @angular/material/theming despues de actualizar a angular/Material15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15

Despues de instalar angular15, my application funciona correctamente. Pero al instalar angular/material15, las paginas pierden algunos de sus estilos. Se descolocan botones, cambia la fuente de las letras, se mueven div. Me he percatado que hay un import que va a un fichero que no encuentra: `@angular/material/theming`. Puede estar esto relacionado? como puedo obtener este archivo? Se renombro?

He usado los siguientes comandos, pero todos con el mismo resultado:

```
ng add @angular/material
npm install @angular/material@latest
ng update @angular/material --force
```

Comment: Cómo estás instalando angular material? Muestra el comando o la definición en el package.json, por favor (yendo a [edit] la pregunta, por supuesto)

Comment: @Alfabravo. Hecho. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa la [guía](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration) y busca los `// TODO(mdc-migration): ...`. Ya no existe ese import desde Angular 12.

Comment: @Alfabravo. Gracias! Practicamente funciona. Solo hay un boton con un diseño raro. Podrias indicarme, por favor, que hacer en los casos del TODO? No se como solucionarlo o donde mirar.

Comment: @Alfabravo. Es mas bien un boton dentro de un DIV que esta descolocado y hace que el DIV sea mas grande de lo que deberia

Comment: @Alfabravo. La clase es button-add